# Do gravitational waves violate the information paradox?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves, event-horizon, information

I know when black holes collide, the remnant black hole has a lower mass than the sum of the original two masses. This is due to energy loss via gravitational wave emission.

Does this violate the information paradox? Does this mass come from inside the black holes? I’ve seen some explanations saying that it’s due to relativistic mass from the black holes moving, is this correct? Is this real mass loss? An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/237249

Comment: What does it mean to violate a paradox?